# Getting Soft removal when DestroyImmediate component from gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm writing unity editor script which runs in custom EditorWindow. It selectes the prefab gameObject from inspector.
After picking the gameObject, it goes over each child item, and look for certain component, and checks some value. And if value matches to certain condition, I'm removing the component by calling `DestroyImmediate(component, true)` and at the end I'm saving prefab gameObject.

Once the script is completed, when I saw the child entities where component is being removed, I can see the component entry is present and is marked disabled.

Inspector shows the component like this

> `<Component Name> (Script) (Removed)`

Also, when I open prefab file in text editor, I can see the same script entry under `m_RemovedComponents`

Any idea, what could be wrong here. Is there any other way, maybe reflection to properly remove the component without leaving any traces.

Btw I'm using Unity Editor version `2020.3.31f1`

Comment: well since it is a prefab this shows you the delta against the original prefab it is an instance of. If you want to remove it entirely you will have to do so directly in the prefab, not an instance of it

Comment: Can you please tell how can it can be done with the script.
@derHugo

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: here is the sample of my code
https://gist.github.com/devendrapratap02/dc49ba5b5a68296052c018beb06dc7a5

Here you can see I'm getting my prefab from Selection API, and later saving the prefab

@derHugo

Comment: so just to be sure: By prefab you mean an asset in the `Assets` right? Not an instance of one in the Hierarchy. And are you sure the prefab you have is not a variant prefab of another one?

Comment: its not an asset. Its prefab, now that you mention, it could be an variant prefab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244825/discussion-between-devendra-pratap-singh-and-derhugo).